# "as" or "and"? what's the different?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice

I have the following sentence:

> Finally, we list some properties regrading to XXX, `and(as)` those
>   results will be used later.

I want to state:

1. We next list some properties
2. those properties will be used later, and this is why we list it here.

So, should I use `and` or `as`? or both of them are the same?

Comment: Another possibility: put a semicolon after XXX and drop the conjunction altogether.

Comment: It is unusual way to phrase it, but in this case as = because.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both are used, "as" has a stronger connotation of causality.  As @InitK's comment points out, "as" is being used to explain *why* we are listing properties of X.

I would state it as:

> We list the Ys of X, as this will be useful later in calculating Z.

Since you're already mentioning that these properties will be used later, I would introduce what their eventual use will be.

Generally, I would avoid using "and" as a conjunction when possible:

> I insulted him, **and** he punched me.
>
> I insulted him, **so** he punched me.

The former makes the connection between the two event (insulting and punching) weaker.  "So" conveys the connection more strongly.